# React Google Maps API unable to change the heading

Tags: reactjs, google-maps-api-3, react-google-maps-api

I am using the package `react-google-maps/api` and want to change the heading of the maps. Any suggestions as to how it would be possible to do so?

I have tried to add the heading in the `<GoogleMap/>` Component and I’ve also tried passing the values in the `options` section of the Component but it still won't work.

```js
<GoogleMap
  mapContainerStyle={containerStyle}
  center={center}
  gestureHandling="greedy"
  onLoad={onLoad}
  onUnmount={onUnmount}
  options={{
    scrollwheel: true,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    auto: true,
    noClear: true,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    isFractionalZoomEnabled: true,
    scaleControlOptions: true,
    zoomControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    fullscreenControl: false,
    zoom: 15,
    gestureHandling: 'greedy',        
  }}          
>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heading and tilting are only supported by vector map. In order to use a vector map, there are two steps:

1. [Create a mapID that uses vector map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/webgl) in your Map Management space. (Remember to set MapType to `Javascript`, choose `Vector` as the rendering type, and check `rotation`)
2. Set the heading in the `options` prop, and mapID needs to [be in the `options` prop as well](https://github.com/JustFly1984/react-google-maps-api/pull/1443) according to the PR.

```js
<GoogleMap
    mapContainerStyle={containerStyle}
    center={center}
    zoom={10}
    onLoad={onLoad}
    onUnmount={onUnmount}
    options = {{
        mapId: 'your-map-id',
        heading: 180
    }}
>
```